# Multiple series with different lengths in eCharts in Angular

Tags: angular, echarts

I am trying to use echarts to display multiple series on a single chart, but the series lengths are slightly different. I am trying to use category for the xAxis type.

The issue is that when I plot them any point with an x value that wasn't in the first series is appended to the end of the x axis and not in chronological order. see image below:

[chart with multiple series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgfK9.png)

I have tried using the datasets (current attempt) and encoding the x and y fields, and I have tried creating an array of xAxis data values and assigned them to the xAxis.data option with each series data set to the series.data option but then the points don't match where they're supposed to go on the graph.

I've create a StackBlitz with the code. I appreciate any direction on how to fix this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fw6hui?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You said you want to use `category` as xAxis type, but is it really important for you ? Because if not, I would simply use a `time` type instead (to fix your issue).

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to have to do. I'm not always going to be graphing time, so I was trying to use category to allow more general use case, but I've added a switch case to change the type if the xAxis data is a Date object.